# How to use SqlParameter to define a complete conditional statement where after'where ' ？

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to define a complete SQL statement condition after `where` through the linking implementation of string, because I am not sure how many conditions after `where` there are.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView2.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (!is_first)
    {
        para += "maccount" +" "+ "=" + listView2.Items[i].Text;
        is_first = true;
    }
    else
    {
        para += " or "  + "maccount"+"="+ listView2.Items[i].Text;
    }
}

MessageBox.Show(para);

string sql3 = "select maccount,msum from pharmaceutical_stocks where @para";

SqlParameter[] parameters3 = new SqlParameter[]
{
    new SqlParameter("@para",para)
};

DataTable dt = sqlcontent.dt(sql3, parameters3);
```

I want to find data in the database by the information saved in each item in listview2。

But I get this exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An expression of non-Boolean type is specified in the context in which the condition should be used (near '@para').

Comment: You should use the IN clause. Parameterize the IN clause, while doable, isn't easy.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause#duplicate=0

Comment: You are not using parametrization correctly. The @para should be the variable.
Basically your where cluse is just a strin "where 'para'"
What you are building with para is  dynamic SQL. Try
string sql3 = "select maccount,msum from pharmaceutical_stocks where " + para

Comment: Parameters are *parameters*, not code or string interpolation placeholders. They're used to pass values to the compiled query, not modify the query itself. If you want to retrieve rows for a specific `macaccount` the query should be `... WHERE macaccount=@account`. In this case `@account` is a parameter. When the compiled query gets executed the database engine will pass the parameter value to it

Comment: Perhaps a table type parameter would be a better choice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code above cannot work!.
Parameters cannot be used to replace blocks of text within the query, whether the text is a column name, a table name, operator or some combination of the previous elements.

They can be used only to transfer **values** to the database engine where they are properly used with the query text and the placeholders inside that query without a text-replace operation. So instead of trying to build a series of OR statements around the *maccount* field, you should use the IN clause and build an array of parameters. The single parameters placeholders can be constructed by code internally concatenating a string without worrying about Sql Injection.
At the end you insert the parameters placeholders (not the values) in the query text and pass the list with all defined parameters to your method

```
StringBuilder inText  = new StringBuilder();
List<SqlParameter> prms = new List<SqlParameter>();
for(int i = 0; i < listView2.Items.Count; i++)
{
    SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@p" + i, SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    p.Value = listView2.Items[i].Text;
    prms.Add(p);
    inText.Append($"@p{i},");
}
if(inText.Length > 0) inText.Length--;
string sql3 = $@"select maccount,msum 
                from pharmaceutical_stocks 
                where maccount in({inText.ToString()})";
DataTable dt = sqlcontent.dt(sql3, prms.ToArray());
```

Comment: You should probably mention Dapper as well

Comment: thank  you very much!but I get another exception :System. Data. SqlClient. SqlException: Syntax error near "."

Comment: @yoga my bad, forgotten an $ before the query text. See the updated code.     _string sql3 = $@"select maccount,msum ....._

Answer (score -1):

The idea behind my code is same as Steve's answer but my suggestion to use string.Join for building params string. Assuming parameters is SqlParameter[]

```
const string sql = "select maccount, msum from pharmaceutical_stocks where maccount in ({0})";
string sqlCommand = string.Format(sql, string.Join(",", parameters.Select(p => p.ParameterName)));
```

This way you don't worry about comma in the end. The only thing you still want to check if there are indeed some items in listView2

Comment: That's how SQL injection attacks happen. What one of those non-parameters contained `'); drop table pharmaceutical_stocks;--` ?

Comment: No, its not. Injected are param Name and not the value. The result query is like `select maccount, msum from pharmaceutical_stocks where maccount in ('@account1','@account2')`

Comment: In that case the code doesn't work at all. Those are strings. Not parameters. `'@account2'` is a string value starting with `@` followed by `a` etc.

Comment: Obviously you need to use this command text with parameters array like Steve does `DataTable dt = sqlcontent.dt(sqlCommand, parameters.ToArray());`

Comment: Ah, I see. I need to remove some quotes